# Android ViewPager non-title page indicator

Tags: android, android-viewpager, xamarin

I'm using a `ViewPager` to host multiple views, and I want something to visually show where the user is currently located. I **don't** want to use `PagerTitleStrip` or `PagerTabStrip` cause I don't want titles.

I want something similar to the horizontal line in the default launcher of the **Nexus 4** shown in here:

[image]

When you swipe left or right, there is a slightly bigger rectangle that shows your position relative to the pages.

How can I do this?

**PS:** I can't use any library cause the code is going to be written in C# with `Xamarin`, also can't use any `Xamarin` component cause license won't let it have any more components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [ViewPagerIndicator Library](http://viewpagerindicator.com). This has an option for your desire.

---

**ADDITION**

I found this official Xamarin [ViewPagerIndicator Library](http://docs.xamarin.com/samples/ViewPagerIndicator/). Maybe this would help.

Comment: Specifically, `UnderlinePageIndicator` is along the lines of what you seek.

Comment: "I can't use any library cause the code is going to be written in C# with Xamarin" -- learn enough Java to read how `UnderlinePageIndicator` works and reimplement it, then.

Comment: @CommonsWare, yes, the best option is to learn how it works, translate it into C#.

Comment: Can't reimplement it, the idea of using Xamarin and looking for solutions as this one is not to write additional code (That what my boss wants). If there is any way of doing this within the **Android SDK** then Xamarin will have it too. If only available through open source libraries then I'll have to pass on this feature

Comment: @jyoon Well my question was how to do this without using libraries since the default android launcher has it I thought maybe there was already a class. If it can't be done, then that should have been the answer. In that case I'll write a simple animation and a 1dp height `View`

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco check out my new answer